# Unable to get Dictionary Item value using sitecore Scheduler event

Tags: sitecore-api

I have created A Sitecore Scheduled Task to send email. I have to read some settings from a Sitecore Dictionary but receiving only key not value.

After debugging I have found that `Sitecore.Context` is null.

Could any one suggest how I can get dictionary values if have no `Sitecore.Context` on controller action?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.TextByLanguage("", Language.Parse("yourlanguage");`?

Comment: What Sitecore version do you have ? On old version was a bug, dictionary.dat is not updated on publishing.